# Porque tengo este Error en el useReducer()

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Estoy usando Typescript , context y useReducer. Cuando paso los argumentos al `useReducer()` tengo un error :

```
   Argument of type 'Contactos[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ContactsState'.
      Property 'contacts' is missing in type 'Contactos[]' but required in type 'ContactsState'.
```

---

```
import { ContactsState } from '../interfaces/interfaces';

type ContactsReducerAction = {
  type: 'delete';
  payload: {
    id: number;
  };
};

export const contactsReducer = (
  state: ContactsState,
  action: ContactsReducerAction
): ContactsState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'delete': {
      let contacts = state.contacts.filter(el => el.id !== action.payload.id);

      return {
        ...state,
        contacts,
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

---

```
interface Contactos {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
}

export interface ContactsState {
  contacts: Contactos[];
}
```

---

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import { ContactsState } from '../interfaces/interfaces';
import { contactsReducer } from '../reducers/contactsReducerContext';

const INITIAL_STATE: ContactsState['contacts'] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'jdoe@gmail.com',
    phone: '555-555-5555',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Karen Williams',
    email: 'Karen@gmail.com',
    phone: '222-222-2222',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Henry Johnson',
    email: 'henry@gmail.com',
    phone: '111-111-1111',
  },
];

export const ContactsContext = createContext({});

interface props {
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[];
}

const ContactsProvider = ({ children }: props) => {
  const [contactState, dispatch] = useReducer(contactsReducer, INITIAL_STATE); // El error aparece aquí!!!

  return (
    <ContactsContext.Provider value={{ contactState }}>
      {children}
    </ContactsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ContactsProvider;
```

Comment: El tipo de dato de `INITIAL_STATE` es `Contactos[]` en vez de `ConstactStates`. Posiblemente la asignación la estés haciendo mal.

Comment: `ContactsState['contacts']` así hago referencia a `Contactos[]`